# Error with kernel installation of 2.6.25 on Fedora13 [2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE]

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Iam doing  following steps to compile linux kernel

1. downloaded and tar the the linux kernel version 2.6.25
2. patched with tproxy(for transparent proxying support)
3. `make mrproper`
4. `make config` (selected default options mostly)
5. `make -j 4 && make modules_install && make install`

I am getting following error:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not found module snd_hda_codec_realtek

ERROR: modinfo: could not found module snd_hda_codec

ERROR: modinfo: could not found module dell_wmi

ERROR: modinfo: could not found module drm_kms_helper

grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template
```

How to resolve the above errors?

Comment: what is your earlier kernel version?

Comment: I started with Fedora 13 itself.